# twitter bootstrap affix / scrollspy width and scrolling issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix, scrollspy

I've nearly got it all working:
http://firestream.net/2013/index.php?go=stats

Here are the two problems I'm having:

1) as you scroll down I'd like the side nav list to stay at the very top of the screen, not where it stays currently
2) the width of the nav list squishes in as you scroll down

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <ul class="nav nav-list" id="sidenavbar">
              <li class="active"><a href="#top10pt"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Top 10 Pages Today</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#top10pa"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Top 10 Pages Alltime</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#daily"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Daily Stats</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="#top10rt"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Top 10 Referalls Today</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="span9" id="content">
       <section id="top10pt">
       ...
       </section>
       <section id="top10pa">
       ...
       </section>
       <section id="daily">
       ...
       </section>
       <section id="top10rt">
       ...
       </section>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#sidenavbar').affix();
$('body').scrollspy();
</script>
```

Any help or advice would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the following CSS, the `#sidebarnav` will be positioned when the affix plugin adds the `.affix` class to the item. The `.affix` class will make the positioning fixed and, as mentioned on the docs, you should do the positioning yourself.

```
#sidebarnav.affix {
  top: 56px;
}
```

[read the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix): *You must manage the position of a pinned element and the behavior of its immediate parent. Position is controlled by affix, affix-top, and affix-bottom. Remember to check for a potentially collapsed parent when the affix kicks in as it's removing content from the normal flow of the page.*

Comment: OK that's pretty close.  I added a very similar snippet of CSS to the page.  The width part seems ok.  The effect I'm going for is on this page, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global

Comment: If you scroll down on that link, you'll see the nav list scroll up and then stick in place.  Mine currently stays fixed immediately instead of scrolling up a tad until the header goes off the screen.

Comment: [read the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) You must manage the position of a pinned element and the behavior of its immediate parent. Position is controlled by affix, affix-top, and affix-bottom. Remember to check for a potentially collapsed parent when the affix kicks in as it's removing content from the normal flow of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to address similar issues with my scrollspy.

First, the affix class should be applied to the element. The reason why is that the scrollpy function will look for this class and change it from affix to affix-top depending on where the user is on the page or whether or not the document was just loaded. This will help solve your position problem as the scrollspy object will sit in normal document flow until the user begins scrolling.

- Note, make sure to make a chain selector for the object for when the affix class is present so you can position is away from the very top of the page. Something like ul.nav.affix: {top: ##px;} worked well for me.

Second, when affix is applied, your removing it from normal document flow because position: fixed; gets applied. If you are defining the width of your scrollspy using a relative unit, it will shift it's width because the relationship between the width of the scrollspy and its parent has changed (its has a different parent and is no longer contained by you 'span-3' ul).